# Bootstrap Popover Placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap popover. But i want to that popover's left start of the element's left. In normally popover location open of the element( for top and bottom). I want to element's left pos and popover left  pos is same. how can i do this?

Thank you.

```
$("#all-cat-menu").popover({template: '<div id="all-cat-popover" class="popover top"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
                        trigger:'click',
                        content:$("#myContent").html(),
                        placement:'bottom',
                        html:true});
```

Comment: not same question.. i want to change left position of popover.i mean that not my ancestor's center, i want of popover's left pos same ancestor's left position